# Relationship between Hecke algebra and center of universal enveloping algebra (and the Harish-Chandra isomorphism)

Tags: lie-groups, symmetric-spaces, hecke-algebras

Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group of noncompact type and let $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup. Let $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{p} \oplus \mathfrak{k}$ be the Cartan decomposition coming from some Cartan involution, and let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a maximal abelian subalgera of $\mathfrak{p}$. Let $A$ be the subgroup of $G$ corresponding to $\mathfrak{a}$. It is known that $G$ can be decomposed into double cosets of $K$ indexed by elements in some choice of Weyl chamber associated to $\mathfrak{a}$. Here's a geometric way to think about this statement: $G$ acts on pairs of points of $G/K$, i.e. acts on $G/K \times G/K$. Orbits under this action correspond to double cosets of $G$ under $K$ which in turn correspond to relative positions of points. Suppose I fix two points, say $1 K$ and $g K$. Consider the element $X$ in the tangent space at $1 K$ (which I can identify with $\mathfrak{p}$) such that $\exp{(X)} \ K = g K$ (i.e. what direction $g K$ is in relative to $1 K$). Then there is precisely one vector in our chosen Weyl chamber in the orbit of $X$ under $K$.

I can use the $(K, K)$ double cosets to give me averaging operators on, say, $C^\infty(G/K)$ which can be described geometrically as follows. Given $f$ and a double coset $K a K$ with $a$ an element in the exponentiated Weyl chamber, I get an operator $T_a$ where $T_a f(x K) = \text{average value of f on the orbit of $a x K$ under the stabilizer of $x K$ (i.e. $x K x^{-1}$)}$. Since $(G, K)$ is a Gelfand pair I get a commutative algebra which, if I'm understanding things correctly, is basically the same things as the Hecke algebra. These operators all commute with the $G$ action on $G/K$.

Now recall a geometric way of defining the Laplacian is as follows (this definition also works for Riemannian manifolds): given $f(x)$ let $F(r,x)$ be the average value of $f(x)$ over a sphere of radius $r$ centered at $x$. Then $\Delta f(x) = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{F(r, x) - f(x)}{r^2}$. Essentially the Laplacian tells you how much the value of a function differs infinitesimally from average value on neighboring points.

Now using our above operators $T_a$, we can define Laplacian like operators for every point in our Weyl chamber: given $X$ let $\Delta_X f(xK) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{T_{\exp(tX)} f(xK) - f(xK)}{t^2}$. Again, thus we get a bunch of Laplacian like differential operators that commute with the $G$-action. One question I have is if these operators have names. Note that if the rank of $G$ is $n$, then any Weyl chamber is a cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with exactly $n$ extremal rays. Just computing the above operators for these extremal rays should essentially allow us to obtain all the others (I have to think about this part a bit more). The upshot is that we get $n$ Laplacian like differential operators which commute with the group action. Note that in the rank 1 case, we essentially only get one operator and this operator is exactly the Laplacian (up to scaling).

On the other hand, there is a theorem which states that the algebra of differential operators on $G$ which commute with the $G$ action on itself (i.e. the center of the universal enveloping algebra) is generated by $n$ elements if $G$ has rank $n$. Given an element in the center of the universal enveloping algebra, I obtain a differential operator on the symmetric space which commutes with the $G$ action by lifting functions on $G/K$ to a function on $G$ (which is constant on $K$ cosets), applying the operator, and then projecting down by averaging on $K$ cosets.

My questions is how these two different algebras of differential operators on $G/K$ that commute with the $G$ action relate to each other. A bit of googling leads me to suspect that what I'm describing is very closely related to the Harish-Chandra isomorphism. However, my background is more in the geometry direction than representation theory direction, so I often find the representation theory literature impenetrable.

EDIT: I've thought about this a bit more, and want to provide further evidence that this is related to the Harish-Chandra isomorphism (again, my background in representation theory is weak, so my preemptive apologies if I say something stupid). Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be as before (a maximal abelian subalgebra contained in $\mathfrak{p}$). Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{a}$. Let $a_1, \dots, a_n$ be extremal rays in some choice of Weyl chamber in $\mathfrak{a}$. Let $B_i = \sum_{w \in W} (w.a_i)^2$ where $W$ is the Weyl group. The $B_i$'s are order two elements in $\mathcal{A}$ and are evidently invariant under ther $W$ action (and they are all distinct). We thus get $n$ elements in $\mathcal{A}^W$. However, these $B_i$'s are (at least heuristically) an enveloping algebra version of the Laplacian like operators I presented above (really to get the above operators you would need to subsequently average these $B_i$s over the orbit of the $K$ action on $\mathfrak{g}$, but it's not clear to me that what you would subsequently get is expressible as an element in the universal enveloping algebra though it would make sense as a differential operator on $C^\infty(G)$). Do these elements generate $\mathcal{A}^W$?

Comment: Shouldn't  $ \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} F(r, x)$ be zero? I think you need to either take another derivative or else divide by $r$.  $F(r,x)$ will typically look like $a + b r^2+$ lower-order terms, and you're trying to extract $b$. Similarly, for your generalized Laplacians, you may need to divide by a power of $t$.

Comment: Consider the case of $G = SL_n(\mathbb R)$, $K= SO_n(\mathbb R)$, $x=1$, $f = \operatorname{tr} ( M M^T)$, which is left and right $K$-invariant, so defines a function on $G/K$ invariant under the left action of $K$. Then $\mathfrak p$ is the space of symmetric matrices with trace zero. For a symmetric $X$, $ f( e^{X t}) = \operatorname{tr} ( e^{2 X  t} ) = n+ 2 t \operatorname{tr}(X) + 2 t^2 \operatorname{tr}(X^2) + \dots $. Now $\operatorname{tr}(X)=0$ and $\operatorname{tr}(X^2)>0$ so you will only see the second order term taking this limit, even if $X$ is an extremal ray.

Comment: To get the other operators you probably want to subtract the averages for different points $X$ to cancel the lower powers of $t$ so you can divide by higher powers of $t$ and get a well-defined limit. Or you can consider polynomial approximations to $T _{ \operatorname{exp}(X)} f(xK)$ and extract coefficients, which brings the ring of invariant polynomials into the picture.

Comment: @WillSawin, you are correct. I have corrected it now.

Comment: You still will only get second-order operators (which for a simple group should just be the Laplacian). To get higher-order generators, you need to divide by a higher power of $t$, so you need to artificially force the second derivative in $t$ to be $0$.

Comment: @WillSawin please see my edit to the post (at the bottom).

Comment: For a semisimple group, the number of order two elements in $\mathcal A^{W}$ is equal to the number of simple factors. So these won't generate the whole algebra. For almost every group, it has generators in higher degrees.